# Core Data strange issue with properties

Tags: objective-c, core-data, properties, crash, relationship

I just noticed a strange issue with my app using Core Data (which didn't happen before).

Here is a section of code:

```
NSArray *allTransactions = [CDMTransaction transactionsFrom:_dateFrom to:_dateTo bankAccounts:_displayedBankAccounts categories:categories recipients:recipients tags:tags unclosedOnly:unclosedTransactionsOnly];
for (CDMTransaction *transaction in allTransactions) {
    if (transaction.inverseTransaction != nil) {
        ...
    }
}
```

What causes the issue is the call to `transaction.inverseTransaction`.

`CDMTransaction` is a subclass of `NSManagedObject`, which contains several properties and relationships (like `inverseTransaction`).

Everything worked fine until now, but I get an crash when this property is called:
**CoreData: error: warning snapshot_get_value_as_object called on NULL**, and it sends me to the `inverseTransaction` property implementation.

But when I try to log the allTransactions array contents, before entering the "for" loop, it just work fine!

Here is the updated code:

```
NSArray *allTransactions = [CDMTransaction transactionsFrom:_dateFrom to:_dateTo bankAccounts:_displayedBankAccounts categories:categories recipients:recipients tags:tags unclosedOnly:unclosedTransactionsOnly];
NSLog(allTransactions: %@, allTransactions);
for (CDMTransaction *transaction in allTransactions) {
    if (transaction.inverseTransaction != nil) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And what I get in the log console:

```
2015-01-11 11:54:51.613 Cash[14383:1403274] allTransactions: (
    "<CDMTransaction: 0x7b94d4a0> (entity: CDMTransaction; id: 0x7b935f30 <x-coredata://12493FBF-2D83-469C-9610-D7C29E21F12B/CDMTransaction/p1> ; data: <fault>)"
)
```

Without any issue after...

It doesn't seem to be an issue with the inverseTransaction property because it does the same with all other properties (`NSString`, `XNSNumber`, ...) and relationships...

What is wrong?

**Edit 1: when it crashes I get the property implementation line highlighted in green with a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error (and not an EXC_BAD_ACCESS)**

**Edit 2: The app doesn't crash anymore when I add `request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = NO;` to my `NSFetchRequest`... So it seems to be OK now, but why do I have to write that? It didn't need it before...**

Comment: Are you able to follow the steps of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845066/exc-bad-access-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller? This in order to get other details about the problem

Comment: Where/How can I "Set NSZombieEnabled, MallocStackLogging, and guard malloc in the debugger"? I never used it before.. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Here you can find how to enable zombies, etc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-up-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4

Comment: Thank you, I will check that. But have you seen my last edit on my post? I managed to get it work, but using a property on NSFetchRequest that I didn't need to set before... Any idea? :)

Comment: Yes. But with more details on the error it should be better to understand the problem.